# What are embryophytes? And how are they characterized?

Tags: botany

What does it mean when it's said that plants are embryophytes?
What are the specific characteristics that help determine that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name derives from their innovative characteristic of nurturing the young embryo sporophyte during the early stages of its multicellular development within the tissues of the parent gametophyte.

source
https://www.revolvy.com/main/index.php?s=Embryophytes&item_type=topic

Similar definitions are in the New World Encyclopedia and Merriam Webster Dictionary.